# Move File : How to combine date and extension in powershell script?

Tags: powershell, file-io

I want to move file to another folder based on date and extension(eg: .zip).For now, my script can successfully move the file to another folder based on date. Unfortunately, I do not have the idea how to do the script based on extension. Can someone help me to figure out this thing ? How to combine both date and extension in one script in order to move file ? Here is my code based to move file based on date.

```
$fs = dir C:\move_test_3\ | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.date -lt (((get-     
date).addDays(-1)).date) } 
  if ($fs) 
  {
   move-item -path $fs -destination "C:\move_test_4"
       }
```

I have tried this, but it is not right.

```
$fs = dir C:\move_test_3\ | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.date -lt (((get-     
date).addDays(-1)).date) } 
  if ($fs -and $file.Extension.Equals('.zip'))
  {
   move-item -path $fs -destination "C:\move_test_4"
       }
```

Comment: Do you want to move a single file, or all files that match the criteria?

Comment: @Dangph The folder contained .txt and .zip files. And I want to move all files which only involving .zip file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this many ways. Here is a one-liner:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\Move_test_3\*.zip | 
where {$_.lastwritetime -lt (get-date).adddays(-1)} |
move-item -destination c:\move_test_4\
```

Checking for file extension is done later in the code below. As you already know which extension you are interested in, you might as well specify that in the get-childitem

```
if ($fs) {
  foreach ($file in $fs) {

   if ($file.Extension -eq '.zip') {
       //move $file
    }
  }
}
```

You might also just filter by .zip at the beginning

```
dir C:\move_test_3\ -include '.zip'
```

Comment: I try to do the first one that you suggest, but somehow it returs this, Method invocation failed because [System.IO.FileInfo] doesn't contain a method named 'Extension'. I also try to filter the '.zip' at the beginning, but it doesnt move my file at all. @adil hindistan

Comment: There is also -file option for gci if you are using later versions of PowerShell (I believe it was added with v3) in case there are directories in the path and you only want the files

Comment: Can you explain more ? This is my first time to involve in powershell scripting. Still a newbie.

Comment: Which part you need help with?